# Rounding times in time inputs to full hours or half-times

Tags: javascript, html, date, datetime

**I need:**

XX:01 through XX:14 to round down to XX:00

XX:15 through XX:29 to round up to XX:30

XX:31 through XX:44 to round down to XX:30

XX:45 through XX:59 to round up to (XX+1):00

**Notes:**

1. I gave only two cases in the code, ultimately I have more of them
2. For example, I added additional inputs in the code that are not used, they are not valid
3. They must check automatically if it has been entered.

**My code html:**

```html
<table>

<tr class="day"> 
  <td class="forUser1"><input type="time" class="start" id="start_1"></td>
  <td class="forUser2"><input type="time" class="end"  id="end_1"></td>
</tr>

<tr class="day">
  <td class="forUser1"><input type="time" class="start"  id="start_2"></td>
  <td class="forUser2"><input type="time" class="end" id="end_2"></td>
</tr>

</table>
```

**I tried:**

```
funtion dist (parting) {
dist = parting.split(":");
const distDate = new Date(0, 0, 0, dist[0], dist[1], 0);
(...)
}


document.querySelector('table').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  const classList = e.target.classList
  if (classList.contains('start') || classList.contains('end')) {

    const tr = e.target.parentNode.parentNode
    const [start, end] = [...tr.querySelectorAll('.start,.end')]
    (...)
  }
})
```

I thought that this time should be divided into individual components, but honestly I will take every good way out of this situation

Comment: So you want to round them down when you submit the data or you want to round it off in the input itself while the time is being entered?

Comment: If it were possible  round it off in the input itself while the time is being entered

Comment: With the help of RobG's suggestion in the comments, I have made a minor change to the if statement to round up the hour if the minutes are between 44 and 60. Do check out the new edited logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just get all the input elements using the [querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) method and then add an `change` listener to each one which will run a function called say, `roundFunc` that will round the numbers for you and then assigned the new rounded numbers back to the input value.

Check and run the following Code Snippet or open this [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/kagalajaca/edit?html,js,output) for a practical example of the above approach:

```js
const timeInputs = document.querySelectorAll('table input.start, table input.end');

const roundFunc = e => {
  let x = e.target.value.split(':');
  if (x[1] > 00 && x[1] < 15) {
    x[1] = "00";
  } else if (x[1] > 44 && x[1] < 60) {
    x[0] = x[0] < 10 ? "0" + (parseInt(x[0]) + 1) : parseInt(x[0]) + 1;
    x[1] = "00";
  }
  else {
    x[1] = "30";
  }
  e.target.value = x.join(':');
}

timeInputs.forEach(input => {
    input.addEventListener('change', roundFunc);
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="day"> 
    <td class="forUser1"><input type="time" class="start" id="start_1"></td>
    <td class="forUser2"><input type="time" class="end"  id="end_1"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="day">
    <td class="forUser1"><input type="time" class="start"  id="start_2"></td>
    <td class="forUser2"><input type="time" class="end" id="end_2"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

However, it would be cleaner to round it off when the data is being submitted tbh since the end-user won't end up confused by the change of numbers as they typed. To round the numbers when you're ready to send the data to your server, you can just run the above function `roundFunc()` right before you are going to submit the data instead.

Comment: @RobG I'm not really following what you mean. Can you clarify your comment so I can update the answer accordingly.

Comment: Or even better, add it as an answer here and I'll upvote it if I understand what you're getting at.

Comment: @RobG Nevermind. I understood what you meant and updated the code snippet. Regardless, do add it as an answer and I'll upvote it. Cheers.

Comment: @RobG Not really sure what you mean by "impossible to enter any other value.... 00 or 30 for minutes.". Can you add the more recommended approach to this as an answer please.

Comment: Also, I added a JSBin link to the answer with the above edited code and the output result seems to be working fine for me.

Comment: Changing to the change event and correctly dealing with hours has fixed things in Safari and Chrome, but it still doesn't work in Firefox.

Comment: What part of the logic above do you think is causing the browser incompatibility?

Comment: The behaviour of the Firefox time input is affected by the listener. E.g. focus on a freshly reset time input (no values) and enter 2, 1, 0, tab, which sets the time to 02:10 and moves focus to the next input. Because am/pm hasn't been set, the change event doesn't fire. Go back and select "am" and the change event fires immediately, changing the minutes to 00. Now go back and change the 2 to 3 and the minutes go to 30.

Answer (score 1):

It might not be the most elegant, but it seems to work:

```js
let start = document.querySelector(".start");
start.addEventListener("change", roundTime);

/*
  01:00 .. 01:14 -> 01:00
  01:15 .. 01:44 -> 01:30
  01:45 .. 01:59 -> 02:00
*/
function roundTime(event) {
  let time = event.target.value.split(":");
  let hours = parseInt(time[0]);
  let mins = parseInt(time[1]);

  if (mins < 15) {
    mins = 0;
  } else if (mins < 45) {
    mins = 30;
  } else if (mins < 60) {
    mins = 0;
    hours = (hours + 1) % 24;
  }

  let rounded = [hours.toString().padStart(2, '0'), mins.toString().padStart(2, '0')].join(":");
  let result = document.querySelector(".result");
  event.target.value = rounded;
}
```

```html
<input type="time" class="start">
```

Comment: it is possible to refresh it in the same field (the result in the input field), after leaving this field updated?

Comment: Yes, just assign the result to the source `input` element instead. See updated answer.

Comment: Here is the automatic setting at the time of entry, I can not enter the minutes after entering the hour, I would like to be able to change and only after going to another field (leaving this field) the value will round up (i use google chrome, I don't have a bar with minutes and hours)

Comment: I tried in in FF and Chromium and I have separate inputs for Hours, Minutes and AM/PM. Only after entering the minutes does the change take effect. That sounds like what you want. But it is possible that it works differently in your browser and locale. Sadly I can't currently reproduce that. Also see [the MDN article on time input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time).

Comment: You could try if changing the event type from `change` to `input` achieves your desired result.

Comment: The change or blur events are much better options. Input will attempt to modify the value at every keystroke, making the inputs practically impossible to use.